# What are some examples of propositional logics which are not functionally complete?

Tags: propositional-calculus

In particular I'm interested in propositional logics with semantics given by truth tables which are not functionally complete, but which *can* define all their constant truth functions.

I think the restriction of Post's lattice to clones containing the constants shows that there are six two-valued cases.

One many-valued example is R. B. Angell's connexive logic CC1. (See [1].) Are there any other reasonably well-known or interesting examples here?

[1] *McCall, S.*, [**Connexive implication**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2270458), J. Symb. Log. 31, 415-433 (1966). [ZBL0161.00405](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0161.00405).